# An alien lands on Earth, women believes he's good turns out he's bad

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember watching a film some time ago (not more than 5 years ago, so the film probably isn't older than 2007 I'd guess). It was in English. I watched it in Europe. I think in Paris to be exact but I'm not really sure though. I remember there was an alien who landed on Earth (don't remember how exactly he landed and whether the landing itself was shown).

The government (or some special agency, government-related) found him. The agents (one main guy asking questions and some other ones acting as defense I think) were interrogating the alien which was tied to a chair. They were in a metal room. I remember there was a woman who somehow knew the alien's language and was there as a translator. She believed the alien was good. While interrogating the alien was thirsty but the agents refused giving him water (I think there was water on the table which they said would give to him if he answered the questions). The woman felt sorry for the alien as she believed he was good (he was saying he came to Earth for peaceful purposes only). I think the agent was also electrocuting him. I think the woman convinced the agent to give him a bit water or she gave it herself to the alien when the agent left the room (I think the agent left the room a few times).

The agent left the room in a hurry and I think the alarm lights (flashing red ones) went on. After some time the woman freed the alien and tried to escape from the facility with him though he had trouble moving. After some time the woman found some stairs going upwards on which she went with the alien. It was like a small observation point (look more or less like a small room with 2 walls made of glass). When the woman looked through the window she saw destroyed buildings and it turned out the aliens wanted to invade Earth (which they did). I think the alien said "Sorry" but I'm not really sure. The film ended there.

Comment: sounds a little like "the day the earth stood still"

Comment: @IanF1 No, that's not it. It's _The Arrival Of Wang_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an Italian movie [*The Arrival of Wang*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1712502/) (2011) that mostly fits your description.

Here is a [link](https://letterboxd.com/film/the-arrival-of-wang/) to a brief summary and reviews on the same.

> Chinese-language interpreter Gaia is called up out of the blue by the Italian authorities with an urgent and confidential translation assignment. She is whisked away to a secret underground location and ushered into a pitch-black room where she is asked to interpret the harsh interrogation of a mysterious presence, the eponymous Mr. Wang.